# PHP Deprecated: Non-static method RestrictAllowedPlugins::filter() should not be called statically in /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecation-warning

using PHP 7.4.21, wordpress core5.7.2. Found the two pieces of code the deprecation warning mentions, but why is there an issue and how to fix it?

The issue is with this line of code in the below lines of code:

```php
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

Here's the snippet from class-wp-hook.php on line 292....

```php
// Avoid the array_slice() if possible.
if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
    $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
} elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
} else {
    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
}
```

The RestrictAllowedPlugins plugin's filter function of issue is here:

```php
if( !class_exists('RestrictAllowedPlugins') ) {
class RestrictAllowedPlugins {

function filter($plugins) {
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_network_plugins' ) ) // Disable restrictions for network admins
        return $plugins;

    $allowed_plugins = get_site_option( 'allowedplugins' );
    
    if( !is_array( $allowed_plugins ) )
        return $plugins;

    unset( $plugins[ plugin_basename(__FILE__) ] );

    foreach( array_keys($plugins) as $key ) {
        $plugin_key = str_replace( '/', ':', $key );
        if( !isset( $allowed_plugins[ $plugin_key ] ) )
            unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
    }

    return $plugins;
}
```

This is a filter with the callback:

```php
add_filter( 'all_plugins', array('RestrictAllowedPlugins','filter') );
```

Comment: I can't find `RestrictAllowedPlugins` anywhere, is it a free/paid/private plugin? Regardless, either change the `add_filter` call to use an instance of the `RestrictAllowedPlugins` class, or change the `filter` method on that class to be static. The former is probably the safer of the two.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did the later earlier, changed filter function to static and it took down my multisite

Comment: It's actually not on the web any longer. It came with a site I inherited. The author is not reachable, https://uk.linkedin.com/in/adam-harley-658150186. See publications. I am trying to update/fix plugin so we can continue to use it. I have been unable to find a replacement for it--unless you know of one. It's purpose is to: Replicates some of the per-site theme toggling functionality for plugins. Affects all sites activated on.It hides some plugins from subdomains reach so only network admin can configure them, but subdomain users can use them

Comment: The latter isn't as safe because other callers might require it to be an instance method. The former is almost definitely safe, with the main exception being trying to figure out what instance to invoke on it. If that plugin uses a factory/singleton  pattern and you don't have the correct instance, some things could get weird. We run a bunch of multisite installs, but unfortunately we don't have a need for that feature so I don't have a comparable plugin. If I needed it, however, I think I'd just do it in code, possibly with a dedicated user role below admin or something

Comment: Code was not purchased. Happy to send the code so you can have a look. It's just one php file

Comment: As long as you don't see an "instance" property in the code, you are probably safe. I would weigh the feature set of this code versus its maintenance going forward. Code that doesn't follow WordPress practices/conventions is one thing, but not following PHP rules is another, and invoking a method in that fashion has been throwing warnings since PHP 5.0 from 15+ years ago.